# How to get the path of a file relative to the Git repository root?

Tags: git, path

Example:

```
$ cd lib
$ git absolute-path test.c # how to do this?
lib/test.c
```

Comment: "absolute path" and "relative to the repo" seem to contradict each other?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [`git ls-files`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files):

```
$ cd lib
$ git ls-files --full-name test.c
lib/test.c
```

This only works for files that have been committed into the repo, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: I had to use a wildcard, or else didn't find the file unless it's in the root of the repo. Use   $ git ls-files --full-name *test.c

Comment: @PedroGarcíaMedina Both commands I posted expect `test.c` to be a path relative to the current working directory. So they're for when you already know where a file is located, but you want to convert the path to an "absolute" path relative to the repo root. If you're trying to instead *search* the entire repo for a file named `test.c`, I recommend running `cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"; git ls-files --full-name '*/test.c' 'test.c'`. Note the quote marks to prevent your shell from interpolating the asterisk.

Answer (score 7):

Pasting the following into your bash terminal will work, regardless of whether "test.c" currently exists or not. You can copy the git-absolute-path function into your .bashrc file for future convenience.

```
git-absolute-path () {
    fullpath=$([[ $1 = /* ]] && echo "$1" || echo "$PWD/${1#./}")
    gitroot="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)" || return 1
    [[ "$fullpath" =~ "$gitroot" ]] && echo "${fullpath/$gitroot\//}"
}

git-absolute-path test.c
```

Comment: Mac OS X "readlink" doesn't have -f (and I presume *BSD).  Suggestions on a portable way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the path of the current directory, relative to the git root, I ended up doing this:

```
if gitroot=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null); then
    directory=$(realpath --relative-to="$gitroot" .)
fi
```

(I'm assuming Bash and I do not know how portable this is.)

Comment: the shell script looks POSIX `sh` compatible but `realpath` might be `GNU` specific

Answer (score 1):

I would like to improve on @gmatht's answer by making it work in an corner-case, by resolving the git root differently:

```sh
git-absolute-path () {
    fullpath=$([[ $1 = /* ]] && echo "$1" || echo "$PWD/${1#./}")
    gitroot="$(echo $(cd $(git rev-parse --show-cdup) .; pwd))" || return 1
    [[ "$fullpath" =~ "$gitroot" ]] && echo "${fullpath/$gitroot\//}"
}
```

The corner-case I'm referring to is when your git repo is in `/tmp` and you're on Windows. `/tmp` seems to be a special case: it refers to your Windows user's temp folder i.e. `C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Temp`. (Not sure "how" it refers to that, it doesn't appear to be a symlink. Like I said, a special case). In any case, `fullpath` can be like `/tmp/your-temp-repo` but `gitroot` can be like `C:/Users/<user>/AppData/Local/Temp/your-temp-repo` but then they're not equal and `git-absolute-path` returns nothing incorrectly.

Comment: This is `msys` specific. In `msys`, `/tmp` refers to the user temp folder in "msys filesystem world" but `git rev-parse` returns the canonical Windows filename.