# How to get the path of the current directory relative to root of the git repository?

Tags: git, bash

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951267/git-get-absolute-path-of-file-relative-to-repo), which tells how to get the path of a particular file relative to the root of the git repo.  But I now want to get the path of the current directory, not a specific file.  If I use

```
git ls-tree --full-name --name-only HEAD .
```

I get the list of all the files in the directory.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking for a way just to read the path? Is there a reason you don't want to use the `pwd` command?

Comment: @BrianaSwift because I want the path relative to the root of the git repo, not the absolute path on the machine.  For example, if I have a repo located at `/home/ewok/git/repo`, and `pwd` would print `/home/ewok/git/repo/src/java`, I want a command that will just give me `/src/java`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

How about:

```
$ git rev-parse --show-prefix
```

From `man git-rev-parse`:

```
--show-prefix
           When the command is invoked from a subdirectory, show
           the path of the current directory relative to the top-level
           directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#git ls-files --full-name  | xargs -L1 dirname | sort -u
```

Use that `git rev-parse --show-prefix` above, awesome

Comment: this gives me the current directory, but also all subdirectories recursively

Comment: actually, that's not quite right.  sometimes it gives me the current directory, sometimes it gives me ONLY subdirectories.  I can't figure out when it gives what

Comment: Is this better? git ls-files --full-name  | head -1 | xargs -L1 dirname | sort -u

Comment: nope.  now it only gives 1 directory, but it doesn't seem to be consistent in which directory it gives.

Comment: `git rev-parse --show-prefix` is one command I'll put in my toolbelt.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto the [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923104/1024811) from Arkadiusz Drabczyk, I just wrapped the suggested command in a shell script (calling it rd.sh, standing for "relative directory" or "repository directory"), and make it print "/" if the `git rev-parse --show-prefix` command would return nothing (at the top level). I'm just starting to use this now, so we'll see how it works!

```
#!/bin/bash
# rd.sh: shows the "repository directory" rather than the entire absolute dir from 'pwd'

RELATIVE_DIR=`git rev-parse --show-prefix`

if [ -z "$RELATIVE_DIR" ]; then
  echo "/"
else
  echo $RELATIVE_DIR
fi
```